# Return a function calling an object's function depending on input parameter

Tags: javascript

In order to sort a private array of objects containing their own private properties, I need to call their `getters` in order to retrieve the correct value.

The code below works -- but it goes through the switch every time the value() function is called. This is inefficient and not an elegant solution.

How would you return a function that doesn't need to check the switch on every call?

Side note: Using `eval` would solve this but I'd rather find another way.

```
const BY_X = 0;
const BY_Y = 1;
const BY_SUM = 2;

function EntryController() {
  const entries = [/* ... */];

  this.sort = function(sortType, order) {
    const value = (entry) => {
      switch (sortType) {
        case BY_X:
          return entry.getX();
        case BY_Y:
          return entry.getY();
        case BY_SUM:
          return entry.getX() + entry.getY();
        default:
          console.error("Unrecognized sortType: " + sortType);
          return 0;
      };
    };

    entries.sort((a, b) => value(a) > value(b) ^ order);
  }
}
```

Comment: To avoid a whole lot of repetitive function calls, you could `entries.map(i => [value(i), i])`, sort by `entries[n][0]` and then unpack the array again. Whether that's actually much more efficient or not should be benchmarked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a function in switch statement like this.

```
const value = (() => {
      switch (sortType) {
        case BY_X:
          return entry => entry.getX();
        case BY_Y:
          return entry => entry.getY();
        case BY_SUM:
          return entry => entry.getX() + entry.getY();
        default:
          console.error("Unrecognized sortType: " + sortType);
          return () => 0;
      };
    }());
```

But I doubt it would significantly affect overall performance. Switch statements are fast even compared to function calls.

Also you could define possible `value` functions outside of the `sort` and simply get one by `sortType`.

```
const values = {
  [BY_X]: entry => entry.getX(),
  [BY_Y]: entry => entry.getY(),
  ...
}

const unknownSortType = () => 0
```

and then

```
this.sort = function(sortType, order) {
  const value = values[sortType] || unknownSortType
  ...
}
```

Comment: The second approach seems similar to Python and I quite like it.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to get the `switch` out of the value logic since it's done once per `sort` call.

```
const BY_X = 0;
const BY_Y = 1;
const BY_SUM = 2;

function EntryController() {
  const entries = [/* ... */];

  this.sort = function(sortType, order) {
  let method;

 switch (sortType) {
    case BY_X:
      method = entries[0].getX; // or from prototype if you know the class
    case BY_Y:
      method = entries[0].getY; // // or from prototype if you know the class
    case BY_SUM:
      method = function(entry){ return entry.getX() + entry.getY(); };
    default:
      console.error("Unrecognized sortType: " + sortType);
      return 0;
  };

const value = (entry) => {
  return method.apply(entry, entry);
};

 entries.sort((a, b) => value(a) > value(b) ^ order);
}
}
```